# Javascript button runs the click event itself once when the page is loaded and doesnt work when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

The answer to this might be quite easy but I couldn't find a solution since everything seems ok. I'm trying to create a google chrome extension and it has a button like this,

```js
document.getElementById("autof").addEventListener("click", autofill());

function autofill() {
  console.log("ENTER");
  document.getElementsByName("session[username_or_email]").value = "sylent";
  document.getElementsByName("session[password]").value = "abcdefg";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>TWITTER</h1>
  <button id="autof">Fill</button>

  <script src="twt.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo. `autofill()` in the `addEventListener` should not have brackets. Using the brackets you are calling the function instead of passing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add the event listener to the button, you should pass in the function without actually calling it.

```
document.getElementById("autof").addEventListener("click", autofill);
```

Comment: You are right about that thats the reason. I thought that to function to be called when clicked it needed parantheses in the end. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Using parenthesis with `autofill()`, you are assigning the *result of calling* your function to the click handler:

```js
document.getElementById("autof").addEventListener("click", autofill());
```

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById("autof").addEventListener("click", autofill);
```